# why installing nativescript gives that tns is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet?

Tags: command-line, nativescript

I m trying to install nativescript, when I do the npm install it works fine but after that when I try to

`tns doctor` or
`tns create`

it gives me this message:

`The term 'tns' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again nativescript`

Someone told me that it is probably something with the environment variables but if so i m not sure what needs to be done

Comment: I tried ``npm i -g nativescript --unsafe-perm`` as well but that didn't help

Comment: What terminal where you using? I suspect it is cmd on Windows? Also, what was the result after installing via npm? Was it successful?

Comment: Have you tried closing the cmd terminal and opening again? Sometimes after installing a global npm script, it does not automatically reflect for using at the terminal, so you will probably need to restart your terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by copying the nativescript node modules to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules and then creating a file called tns.cmd in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm that has the following:

`@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" ( "%~dp0\node.exe" "%~dp0\node_modules\nativescript\bin\tns" %* ) ELSE ( @SETLOCAL @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;% node "%~dp0\node_modules\nativescript\bin\tns" %* )`

and then it worked